# I need help building a regex for a grep to show only the path to running versions of java

Tags: bash, regex, grep, ps

I need help building a grep from ps -ef to return only java paths.

Say we have the following runnning process:

```
bash> ps -ef | grep java
user  pid#      1  1 00:00 ?        00:04:00 /path/to/java/jdk_1.8/bin/java -foo=bar -foo2=bar2 ... etc.
```

What i was from this is to display:

```
bash> ps -ef | grep 'some regex or pattern here'
/path/to/java/jdk_1.8/bin/java
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Apart from the quoting, what's wrong with your command?

Comment: Hi AFH I see the extra quote thanks. The problem isn't the loop itself, maybe that was too much information. All i want to display is the running version of java. I'm looking for some sort of grep: grep -o '/*java' that will only display the java command with no parameters or other attributes from ps

Comment: basically you want a good regex

Comment: Yes that is all I'm looking for. I chose a poor title for the question sorry about that. I've fixed the title and simplified my issue,

Comment: how about `grep -oP "/.*?/bin/java"`  That will go from the first forwardslash it finds,, then try to match up until the first occurrence of /bin/java.  The capital P gets good regex support from Grep

Comment: or  this and doesn't need the -P with grep  even.  `grep -oP "/.*/bin/java"`  Starts from the first forwardslash then matches as much as possible any character up until and including /bin/java.

Comment: Perfect, i can work with both of them from here! Thank you very much.

Comment: yeah and if you had to work it out yourself from scratch, then besides knowing about regexes, you can test things  quickly with echo e.g. `echo user  pid#      1  1 00:00 ?        00:04:00 /path/to/java/jdk_1.8/bin/java -foo=bar -foo2=bar2 ... etc. | grep `   then try patterns.  And you can add a -i to the grep e.g.or mixed with -o so  -io to make it case insensitive(what -i does)..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about `grep -oP "/.*?/bin/java"` That will go from the first forwardslash it finds then try to match up until the first occurrence of /bin/java. The capital P gets good regex support from grep

or this and doesn't need the -P with grep even. `grep -oP "/.*/bin/java"` Starts from the first forward slash then matches as much as possible any character up until and including /bin/java.

And if you had to work it out yourself from scratch, then besides knowing about regexes, you can test things quickly with echo e.g. `echo user pid# 1 1 00:00 ? 00:04:00 /path/to/java/jdk_1.8/bin/java -foo=bar -foo2=bar2 ... etc. | grep` then try patterns. And you can add a -i to the grep e.g.or mixed with -o so -io to make it case insensitive(what -i does).

note- the above is fine but i'd just note that if you're interested in regexes or technicalities-  `.*blah` is a bit interesting because the `.*`(is greedy evaluation) can include a blah so if you have blah 5 times then it'd match blah 5 times. 4 from `.*` and the last from blah. There is `.*?blah`(lazy evaluation)  which would match any character until the first blah. though that requires -P. But in your case looking for /bin/java, you're not going to get /bin/java multiple times in a line so it's no big deal / problem, to use the `.*` without the ?.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit daft to me to get `ps` to print lots of information you don't want, then have to use a complex `grep` expression to extract what you *do* want. The following seems a better approach:

```
ps -C java -o cmd=
```

This will give you the argument list from the command, but you can prune it to argument 0 with the `sed` filter:

```
ps -C java -o cmd= | sed 's%\(/java\) .*$%\1%'
```

If, as is almost certainly the case, there are no spaces in the `java` path, a much simpler filter can be used:

```
ps -C java -o cmd= | sed 's/ .*$//'
```

(In fact the `$` can be omitted, as the "greedy" match will include all characters up to end-of-line, though it is usually as well to include it for legibility.)